# Difficulty with iterating over an array of integers to print out each element in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project in C++ and have encountered an issue with my code that I'm struggling to solve. I'm hoping someone can help me identify and fix the issue.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()

    {
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
```

I wrote the following code in C++ to iterate over an array of integers and print out each element. However, I'm encountering an issue where the loop seems to be going out of bounds and printing out unexpected values.

To fix the issue, I would like specific advice on what changes to make to my code. Additionally, I have tried adjusting the loop condition to use the less-than operator instead of the less-than-or-equal-to operator, and I have also tried adjusting the size of the array or the number of iterations in the loop, but I'm still encountering issues.

Comment: your loop has `size+1` iterations when it starts at `0` and the last iteration `i = size`, but the array has only `size` elements

Comment: Ask youself: If an array has a size of `5`, what are the valid indices of that array?  Is the value of `size` (`5`) one of those indicies?

Comment: "I have tried adjusting the loop condition to use the less-than operator instead of the less-than-or-equal-to operator" - That should have fixed your issue.

Comment: ot: `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` -> `std::size(arr)`. This will save you from running into more issues soon

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)` --> `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`

Comment: "... but I'm still encountering issues." what are those "issues" exactly? What are the issues when you use `<` ?

Comment: `for (auto i : arr) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number What "more issues soon" issues?

Comment: @NathanOliver The `sizeof` version will silently give the wrong result for a pointer (a common cause of SO questions), while `std::size` will give a compilation error.

Comment: With `i < size` instead of `i <= size` your code is correct. I don't see any other issues. If you still have issues, you need to tell us what specific issues you have (like prints strange results, resets your computer, formats your hard drive, ...), or ask another question about this/these issue(s).

Comment: `int arr[] = ...` -- if at all possible, stay away from C constructs in C++. They *look* like making the transition easy, but actually most of the time they just get in the way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Ted Lyngmo has suggested, rather than using raw arrays, you could use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which then work nicely with range-based for loops.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> vec = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    for (auto x : arr) std::cout << x << std::endl;
    for (auto x : vec) std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The c array works with the range based loop as well

Comment: In this specific context yes, but stops working when passed to a function as the array decays to a pointer.

Comment: I agree on suggesting using `std::array` or `std::vector` so +1. I should have done that in my answer but got so caught up in the array business :-). You _can_ pass arrays to functions without the pointer decay though. Just have to take them by reference.

Answer (score 4):

`size` equals `5` in your example, which is correct since there are five elements in the array.

Your `for` loop will on the other hand do **6** iterations:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    // i = [0,1,2,3,4,5]  <- six of them
}
```

The solution to this is to change `<=` into `<` so the loop only uses `0 - 4` as index. Accessing `arr[5]` makes the program have *undefined behavior* and it could do just about anything, including printing garbage values or Vogon poetry.

> specific advice

Your size calculation is correct, although, you use `int` instead of `std::size_t` which is the result of `sizeof`. I suggest using `std::size_t`.

Also, you could put the calculation in a macro to hide the uglyness from the code:

```cpp
#define SIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof *(x))

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < SIZE(arr); i++) {
```

Or better, you could make a function template that returns the correct value and that would result in a compilation error if used with a non-array variable:

```cpp
template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(const T(&)[N]) { return N; }

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size(arr); i++) {
```

Fortunately, [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) already exists in the standard library, so you could just use that directly:

```cpp
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::size(arr); i++) {
```

But the best thing when you want to loop over all elements in an array (or any standard container) is to use a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```cpp
for(int value : arr) {
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

With the range-based `for` loop you'll iterate over all the elements in the array, no more, no less.

Answer (score 2):

The array which you have defined contains only 5 elements. But in the for loop you are trying to access 6th element.

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
```

For the statement above, you have value of size = 5 and you are iterating it from 0 to 5. Your array is indexed only from 0 to 4. Since you are trying to access the index of 5, loop is going out of bound and program prints unexpected garbage value.

If you you are iterating from 0, please make sure that you are not using operator`<=`, and instead use `<`.